# select SQL rows depending on non-identical results of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the columns which is relevant without knowing in advance which ones

I do a:

```
select *
from table
where id = '1'
```

the result i get is maybe 10 rows and 100+ columns

```
|id | column1 | column2  | column3 | column4 | column5 |....
| 1 |    a    |     b    |    c    |    d    |    e    |....
| 1 |    a    |    XXX   |    c    |    d    |    e    |....
| 1 |    a    |     b    |    c    |   YYY   |    e    |....
| 1 |    a    |     b    |    c    |    d    |    e    |....
```

For every row, one (or more) of the columns value is different, but i dont know which one(s)

is there any way i can create a temp table with the first query and do a sub query to display only one columns which doesnt have the same value in all the rows?

so the result would look like this:

```
|id | column2  | column4 |
| 1 |     b    |    d    |
| 1 |    XXX   |    d    |
| 1 |     b    |   YYY   |
| 1 |     b    |    d    |
```

since column 2 and 4 were the ones with non identical data these are the ones I want to see.

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically decide which columns to show? This is going to require dynamic sql and a lot of silly.

Comment: "is there any way i can create a temp table with the first query and do a sub query to display only one columns which doesnt have the same value in all the rows?" The answer is: YES

Comment: @SeanLange the reason i want/need to do this is that i am looking in the database investigating when something goes wrong. The best way to get on the right track finding the problem is looking at what values changed. But since it takes some effort to look at 100+ columns it would be faster only displaying the ones who have different values in them.

Comment: Would something like an archiving trigger would better for you?  Then you can see exactly what changed and even have timestamps and records of historical changes.

Comment: Ahh I see where you going here. I would suggest a slightly different approach. Use some conditional aggregation on each column so that the columns for the rows you are interested in will be populated. Just leave the others as NULL or empty string.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this would require dynamic sql.
Maybe this will help you:

```
CREATE TABLE Column_Relevance
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(column_1))/COUNT(*) AS relevance_column_1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(column_2))/COUNT(*) AS relevance_column_2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(column_3))/COUNT(*) AS relevance_column_3,
#      AND SO ON....
GROUP BY id;
```

All relevance_columns with value < 1 indicate different values for the columns. You can build the whole statement in excel in a few minutes.
Once the table is created, add another column and create a select statement based on the column relevance (e.g. select if(relevance_column_1<1, column_1, else 'ignore') as column_1. This will return the string 'ignore' for all columns, that don't have distinct values. 
This is far from perfect but maybe it helps you a little.

Comment: Be careful here. Your division is an integer divided by an integer so you will always get an integer returned.

Comment: i tested the logic with some data and it returns a floating point value when i divide count(distinct) by count(*). Maybe this is has to do with MySql settings but i would expect Mysql to suggest a "practical" data type in case there is no type defined.

Comment: Well this is tagged with sqlserver not mysql. In sql server COUNT returns an int and will not become a decimal datatype automagically. You would need to multiply by 1.0 to force the math to be decimal division.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could use some aggregation to help. You said you have nearly 100 columns so this could take some effort to create but once it is done it would be fine. And this is just for analysis. You could utilize sys.columns to build the code for you but then we are back in the land of dynamic sql.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , Column1 varchar(10)
    , Column2 varchar(10)
    , Column3 varchar(10)
    , Column4 varchar(10)
    , Column5 varchar(10)
)

insert @Something
values
(1, 'a', 'b', 'c', ' d ', 'e')
, (1, 'a', 'XXX', 'c', ' d ', 'e')
, (1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'YYY', 'e')
, (1, 'a', 'b', 'c', ' d ', 'e')
;

with MinMax as
(
    select ID
        , MIN(Column1) as Col1Min
        , MAX(Column1) as Col1Max
        , MIN(Column2) as Col2Min
        , MAX(Column2) as Col2Max
        , MIN(Column3) as Col3Min
        , MAX(Column3) as Col3Max
        , MIN(Column4) as Col4Min
        , MAX(Column4) as Col4Max
        , MIN(Column5) as Col5Min
        , MAX(Column5) as Col5Max
    from @Something
    group by ID
)

select s.ID 
    , Column1 = case when mm.Col1Max = mm.Col1Min then '' else s.Column1 end
    , Column2 = case when mm.Col2Max = mm.Col2Min then '' else s.Column2 end
    , Column3 = case when mm.Col3Max = mm.Col3Min then '' else s.Column3 end
    , Column4 = case when mm.Col4Max = mm.Col4Min then '' else s.Column4 end
    , Column5 = case when mm.Col5Max = mm.Col5Min then '' else s.Column5 end
from @Something s
join MinMax mm on mm.ID = s.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using distinct ? It returns only unique rows:

select *
from table
where id = '1'

```
|id | column2  | column4 |
| 1 |     a    |    a   |
| 1 |     a    |    a   |
| 1 |     b    |    d   |
| 1 |     b    |    d   |
```

select distinct * from table where id= '1'

```
|id | column2  | column4 |
| 1 |     a    |    a   |
| 1 |     b    |    d   |
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Every row is unique. because it is only there if one of the values changed.